# Python Selenium Code to reply to all comments of a user

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

A friend of mine and I had a bet that I wouldn't be able to find his reddit account. I want to make a fun way of revealing my recent success, so I'm writing a python Selenium code (I can't access the Reddit API).

I am able to log in, navigate to said user, but then I wrote a loop that returns 0. I tried Using Xpath, Name, CSS_Selector, but to no avail.

How can I fix the loop?

Here is the full code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
import time

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
target_user = 'target_user'  
reply_message = 'Message'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  


driver.get('https://www.reddit.com/login/')
time.sleep(2) 


# Fill in the username and password fields and log in
username_field = driver.find_element("name", 'username')
password_field = driver.find_element("name", 'password')
username_field.send_keys(username)
password_field.send_keys(password)
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)  

# Loop through the comments of the target user and reply to each one
driver.get(f'https://www.reddit.com/user/{target_user}/comments/')
time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the comments page to load

comments = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="Comment"]')
for comment in comments:
    try:
        reply_button = comment.find_elements(By.NAME, 'Reply')
        reply_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the reply box to appear
        reply_text_area = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="notranslate public-DraftEditor"]')
        reply_text_area.send_keys(reply_message)
        reply_text_area.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the reply to be posted
        close = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, "Close")
        close.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error replying to comment: {str(e)}")


driver.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loop that returns 0"? Loops don't have a return value.

Comment: Sorry I'm new. I get "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Exit code 0 means the program ended normally. Non-zero codes are used to indicate errors.

Comment: Your script doesn't print anything unless there's an exception. What were you expecting to see instead?

Comment: You'll definitely have Stale Element exception after the first iteration, but since you're not getting that, I'd check the size of the comments array.  (seems like it's only 1 or you'd see the print command fire..  if no reply is posted, then it's 0... or it's that you close without submitting... a textarea (if that's what the field is...) won't submit on enter key...)